# How to get all columns from a Parse platform class

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, schema, back4app

I am trying to get all columns from a class in a Parse platform using cloud code that returns a list/array of all the names of the columns.

I am looking at the [schema section of the documentation](https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#schema), but I can't find how to get the column's names, only adding, deleting, ...

However, I found [this method](https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/v1.11.0/Parse.Schema.html#get), but I haven't figured out how to use it neither found any example.

This is what I have right now (doesn't work, neither is the only thing I tried, but hopefully it can help you understand my situation):

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getAllProperties", async (request) => {
  
    var mySchema;
  
    try {

      mySchema = new Parse.Schema('Entry');

    } catch (error) {
      console.error("ERROR " + error.code + ': ' + error.message);
      return error;
    }
    
    console.log("CloudFunction 'getAllProperties' executed successfully.");
    return mySchema.toString();
  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getAllProperties", async (request) => {
  
    var mySchema;
  
    try {

      mySchema = new Parse.Schema('Entry');
      mySchema = await mySchema.get()

    } catch (error) {
      console.error("ERROR " + error.code + ': ' + error.message);
      return error;
    }
    
    console.log("CloudFunction 'getAllProperties' executed successfully.");
    return JSON.stringify(mySchema);
  
});
```